# Could I have purchased this Mongolian phrasebook while I was in Australia?

Tags: mongolian, physical-resources

While in Mongolia, I was able to purchase the book *Mongolian Phrasebook (Mongolian-English)* by J. Bat-Ireedui & B. Nomunzul, ISBN 978-99973-42-80-5 at the State Department Store in Ulaanbaatar.

Could I have purchased this book while I was in Australia, before travelling to Mongolia?

Answer (score 3):

By conducting a reverse search for the authors, I've come across [this link](http://batireedui.com/travellers-language-guide-mongolian-by-j-bat-ireedui-and-b-nomunzul/), which is the Traveller's Language Guide to Mongolian. There doesn't appear to be a place where you can buy the book, but I'm still searching.

I'll keep this answer updated.